# How to install local pip package from mounted volume in docker-compose

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose, pip, dockerfile

I am working on a project which has dependency on another project.

In live environment, the dependency is published and installed simply using `pip install`. On my local environment, I'd like to be able to install the local dependency instead, using the `pip install -e` command.

The structure is as follow:

```
- Home
--- Project1
----- docker-compose
----- Dockerfile
--- relaton-py
```

In this structure, Project1 has dependency on relaton-py, thus I'd like to "install" this dependency using the local relaton-py.

My docker-compose file looks like:

```
volumes:
      - .:/code
      - /Users/myuser/Dev/Projects/relaton-py:/relaton-py
```

while the Dockerfile looks like:

```
COPY requirements.txt /code/requirements.txt

RUN ["pip", "install", "-e", "relaton-py"]

WORKDIR /code

RUN ["pip", "install", "-r", "requirements.txt"]

# Copy the rest of the codebase
COPY . /code
```

When trying to spin un the environment, I get the following error:

```
=> ERROR [local/web-precheck:latest 11/19] RUN ["pip", "install", "-e", "relaton-py"]                                                                                                                 1.2s
------
 > [local/web-precheck:latest 11/19] RUN ["pip", "install", "-e", "relaton-py"]:
#27 0.685 ERROR: relaton-py is not a valid editable requirement. It should either be a path to a local project or a VCS URL (beginning with bzr+http, bzr+https, bzr+ssh, bzr+sftp, bzr+ftp, bzr+lp, bzr+file, git+http, git+https, git+ssh, git+git, git+file, hg+file, hg+http, hg+https, hg+ssh, hg+static-http, svn+ssh, svn+http, svn+https, svn+svn, svn+file).
#27 0.889 WARNING: You are using pip version 22.0.4; however, version 22.1.2 is available.
#27 0.889 You should consider upgrading via the '/usr/local/bin/python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
------
failed to solve: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = executor failed running [pip install -e relaton-py]: exit code: 1
```

However, if I try not to install this local dependency in the Dockerfile, the entire environment spins up and I am able to access the container and install the package manually with the same command `pip install -e relaton-py`.

Has anyone had to deal with this sort of thing already? Any idea on how to make Dockerfile recognise the files in the mounted volumes?

Comment: `pip install -e` expects a path but it probably isn't finding `relaton-py` in the current working directory, try specifying the path as an absolute path

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For simpler packages, it may be enough to just mount it directly into the `site-packages`.

In your example, you might want to try:

1. putting `relaton-py` (just the package in its source form, e.g. the Git repository) one directory above your Compose file, and
2. adding this line to `docker-compose.yml` under `volumes`:

```yaml
- ../relaton-py/relaton:/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/relaton:ro
```

Assuming you use Python 3.10, this should override whatever gets installed from PyPI during Docker image build with the directory on your host system, mounted in read-only mode to prevent accidental changes from within the container (but any source code changes you make on your main system, of course, will be propagated immediately).

If your package includes native modules and requires compilation for particular OS/architecture, there may be extra steps involved in this.

Comment: Thanks! This solution works with a caveat: Docker needs to be able to mount parent directory.

Answer (score 1):

The volume is only bound when you run the container, the `pip install -e relaton-py` instead is happening when you build the image so the volume bind has not happened yet.

I would suggest embedding relaton-py inside the container.

To do so you need to change the build context to include the relaton-py directory. So in `docker-compose.yml`

```yaml
services:
  Project1:
    build:
      context: ../
      dockerfile: ./Project1/Dockerfile
```

And andjust your Dockerfile accordingly

```
COPY ./relaton-py /relaton-py
RUN ["pip", "install", "-e", "/relaton-py"]

WORKDIR /code

COPY ./Project1/requirements.txt requirements.txt
RUN ["pip", "install", "-r", "requirements.txt"]

COPY ./Project1 .
```

This way the code will be available when you build the image.

Then if you need your local code changes to happen in the container as well you can mount your local directory on top of the directory inside the container by doing:

```yaml
volumes:
      - .:/code
      - ../relaton-py:/relaton-py
```

Comment: This actually does not work. The COPY command fails with the following error: 

`=> ERROR [local/web-precheck:latest 11/20] COPY ../relaton-py /relaton-py                                                                                                                             0.0s
------
 > [local/web-precheck:latest 11/20] COPY ../relaton-py /relaton-py:
------
failed to solve: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to compute cache key: "/relaton-py" not found: not found`

Comment: can you check that the project was copied correctly? create a new Dockerfile with only `COPY ../relaton-py /relaton-py` and `ENTRYPOINT bash` then build it `docker build -t my-test -f newDockerfile .` and run it with `docker run -it --rm my-test` then check if the contents of `/relaton-py` are correct

Comment: You can never `COPY ../anything` into an image; anything that's copied into the image must be part of the build context directory.  If you move the Dockerfile up a directory, though, you can `COPY relation-py/ relation-py/`, `COPY Project1/requirements.txt ./`, and so on.  Injecting code into your image with `volumes:` can lead to inconsistent results.

Comment: That's what I was also guessing @DavidMaze. And that's the reason why I was trying to access the mounted volume and install the dependency from there. Based on this, how do you tackle this issue?

Comment: @DavidMaze thanks for the hint I honestly did not know that. I guess the best option is to just change the build context directory to the parent directory and adjust the paths accordingly. I wll update my answer

Comment: That's not an option for this project @MatteoZanoni . The structure cannot change from the one of the original question

Comment: Ok... hou about just changing the build context and keeping the files in the same place? I will update again